# Swap minus sign from after the number to in front of the number using SED (and Regex)

Tags: regex

I've got a text-file with the following line:

```
  201174480 11-01-1911 J Student            25-07 11585 2 0        SPOED BEZORGEN                       1ST      25,00
  320819019 11-01-1911 T. Student           28-07 13561 1 15786986 DESLORATADINE TABL OMH 5MG          60ST       3,60
  706059901 11-01-1911 ST Student-Student   30-06 14956 1 15356221 METOPROLOLSUCC RET T 100MG         180ST      12,90-
```

I want to change this line with SED into:

```
  201174480 11-01-1911 J Student            25-07 11585 2 0        SPOED BEZORGEN                       1ST      25,00
  320819019 11-01-1911 T. Student           28-07 13561 1 15786986 DESLORATADINE TABL OMH 5MG          60ST       3,60
  706059901 11-01-1911 ST Student-Student   30-06 14956 1 15356221 METOPROLOLSUCC RET T 100MG         180ST      -12,90
```

So I want to swap the minus sign so that I get-12,90 in stead of 12,90- with SED. I tried:

try 1:

```
sed 's/\([0-9.]\+\)-/-\1/g' file.txt > file1.txt
```

try 2:

```
sed 's/\([0-9].\+\)-$/-\1/g' file.txt > file1.txt
```

So there must be something wrong with the REGEX but I donot really understand it. Please help.

Comment: Do you mean you only need to replace `12,90-` with `-12,90`, and do not touch `25-07`? Please check the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
sed 's/\([0-9][0-9,.]\+\)-\($\|[^0-9]\)/-\1\2/g'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/mcaeGp)

The point is that after matching a number and a `-` (see `\([0-9][0-9,.]\+\)-`), there should come either end of string or non-digit (`\($\|[^0-9]\)`). Thus, we have 2 capturing groups now, and that is why we need a second backreference in the replacement pattern (`\2`).

I added a dot `.` to the bracket expression just in case you have mixed number formats, you may remove it if you always have a comma as the decimal separator.

**Pattern details**:

- `\([0-9][0-9,.]\+\)` - Group 1 capturing

  - `[0-9]` - a digit
  - `[0-9,.]\+` - one or more digits, commas or dots
- `-` - a literal hyphen
- `\($\|[^0-9]\)` - Group 2 capturing the end of string `$` or a non-digit (`[^0-9]`)

Answer (score 1):

In your example, both files are identical, but I think I know what you mean.

For this particular file, you want to match a space, followed by zero or more digits, followed by a comma, followed by at least one digit, followed by a dash,
followed by zero or more spaces to the end of the line.

Then you want to replace the space in front of the matched digits and the comma with a dash.   This will do the trick:

```
sed -e 's/ \([0-9]*,[0-9][0-9]*\)- *$/-\1/' <file.txt >file1.txt
```

Comment: It worked with the small file, but I have a larger file and then it failed. I have to look in to it why.

Answer (score 1):

Your first regular expression attempts to match against a string of numbers and `.`s, but the text contains a comma, not a `.`. It does the substitution you want if you replace `[0-9.]` with `[0-9,]`, giving:

```
sed 's/\([0-9,]\+\)-/-\1/g' file.txt > file1.txt
```

However, it also replaces `25-07` in that case with `-2507`. I suggest you explicitly match against the end of the line:

```
sed 's/\([0-9,]\+\)-$/-\1/g'
```

or alternatively, you can demand that the match contains exactly one comma:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\+,[0-9]\+\)-$/-\1/g'
```

I also find these things easier to read if you use the `-r` option to `sed`, which enables "extended regular expressions":

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]+,[0-9]+)-$/-\1/g'
```

Fewer special characters need to be escaped (on the other hand, more literal characters need to be escaped, but I find that tends to be a rarer occurrence).

(Aside: note that `.` usually means "any character", but inside a character class `[.]` it means "literally a `.`", since after all having it mean "any character" in there would be pretty useless.)

Comment: It worked with the small file, but I have a larger file and then it failed. I have to look in to it why.